# Rails - Given @comments how to get all but the last record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have @comments which is either 0 -XXXX number of comments from the DB.

I need this @comments as is as it is used in multiple places.

In one place I need @comments but minus the last record, if any.

How can I do that? w/o rehitting the db?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned, `@comments.pop` will do the job. Another option is to use a range to select which items from the array to use:

```
@comments[0..-2]
```

Answer (score 4):

how about popping off the last one using ruby, and returning a new array?

`@comments.pop`